# Can‘t find CCWaves in cocos2d-objc v3.x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I can't find something like CCWaves(or CCLiquid etc) class in cocos2d v3.x.

but they are exist in cocos2d-x v2.x

so, is it really disappear in cocos2d v3.x? and are there some replaceable class i can use？

thanks！ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my practice I have not used this effect. But in project ccp-tests can be found `EffectsTest.cpp` file. This file contains `Waves::create()` and `Liquid::create()` methods.
If you go over to the definition of a method, you can find such implementation in `CCActionGrid3D.cpp`:

```
Waves* Waves::create(float duration, const Size& gridSize, unsigned int waves, float amplitude, bool horizontal, bool vertical)

Liquid* Liquid::create(float duration, const Size& gridSize, unsigned int waves, float amplitude)
```

EDIT:
Oh, I just noticed, you compare cocos**2d-X** v.2.x and cocos**2d** v.3.x.
According to the [Class Reference](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/index.html), no similar class in cocos2d. But you can find examples of such effect [here](http://www.code4app.net/ios/Use-cocos2d-to-implement-water-ripple-demo/5072966a6803fa0763000000), or migrate to cocos2d-x :)